# Array addition exception error:

Tags: c#

**What's wrong in my coding...?**

This is my coding of adding two dimension array. When i debug my coding then unhandled exception occurs of system.format.something...

code is..

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[,] a = new int[4, 4] 
    { { 1, 1, 1, 1 },
      { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, 
      { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, 
      { 1, 1, 1, 1 } };


    int[,] b = new int[4, 4]
    { { 2, 2, 2, 2 },
      { 2, 2, 2, 2 }, 
      { 2, 2, 2, 2 }, 
      { 2, 2, 2, 2 } };

    int[,] c = new int[4, 4];

    for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
        {
            c[row, col] = a[row, col] + b[row, col];                
        }
    }

    for (int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
    {

        for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
        {
            Console.Write("The value of {0},{1}", c[row, col]);                   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception exactly? On which line? And [write a better title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/158761) based on your specific problem.

Answer (score 3):

You're using `Console.Write` and specifying *two arguments*, yet you only pass *one*.

This:

```
Console.Write("The value of {0},{1}", c[row, col]);
```

Should be along the lines of:

```
Console.Write("The value of row: {0}, column: {1} is {2}", row, col, c[row, col]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Running that code in LINQPad, I get a `FormatException` on the `Console.Write` line.

> **FormatException**
>   Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

This is because you have a format string which takes two arguments, but you only pass one. Try changing that line to

```
Console.WriteLine("The value of {0},{1} is {2}", row, col, c[row,col]);
```